# How to know when SearchView in action bar is closed?

Tags: android, list, listview, searchview

I have a problem: I have a `listView` in a `Fragment`, I implemented a searchView (actionView) to filter the list in the `listView` with the searchView `onQueryTextChange` event. I don't have problems in this part and everything works fine.

```
adapter = new ListaEmpleadosAdapter(getActivity(), empleadoItems, context);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_buscar).getActionView();

SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        try {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("ERROR FragmentEmpleado -> " + e.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

When I search something and press back button in the first time, the soft keyboard is closed. That's normal. When I press back button again, the searchView is closed, that's normal, but the list doesn't return to have the initial items.

How I can get the event when searchView is collapsed (because `searchView.setOnCloseListener` doesn't work) to restore the initial list items? Or any way to restore the initial list items deleting the adapter filter...

HISTORY:

1. The list of employees

[image: list of employees]

2. The list of employees with a specific filter (after the first back button press, the keyboard is closed)

[image: The list of employees with a specific filter]

3. The list of employees with searchView closed (but no restore the original list after second back button press)

[image: list of employees with searchView closed]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How you can solve problem i have same problem #Cristiam Mercado

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a method on `SearchView` that gets fired when the search view collapses (`onActionViewCollapsed`) but there is no event for it. To get around it, I created my own class inheriting from `SearchView` and defining 2 events to capture collapsing and expanding. The class also provides methods to hook up your event handlers.

```
public class MySearchView extends SearchView {

    OnSearchViewCollapsedEventListener mSearchViewCollapsedEventListener;
    OnSearchViewExpandedEventListener mOnSearchViewExpandedEventListener;

    public MySearchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActionViewCollapsed() {
        if (mSearchViewCollapsedEventListener != null)
            mSearchViewCollapsedEventListener.onSearchViewCollapsed();
        super.onActionViewCollapsed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActionViewExpanded() {
        if (mOnSearchViewExpandedEventListener != null)
            mOnSearchViewExpandedEventListener.onSearchViewExpanded();
        super.onActionViewExpanded();
    }

    public interface OnSearchViewCollapsedEventListener {
        public void onSearchViewCollapsed();
    }

    public interface OnSearchViewExpandedEventListener {
        public void onSearchViewExpanded();
    }

    public void setOnSearchViewCollapsedEventListener(OnSearchViewCollapsedEventListener eventListener) {
        mSearchViewCollapsedEventListener = eventListener;
    }

    public void setOnSearchViewExpandedEventListener(OnSearchViewExpandedEventListener eventListener) {
        mOnSearchViewExpandedEventListener = eventListener;
    }


}
```

Comment: This worked for me too, but I had to modify it so that the super.onActionViewExpanded() is called BEFORE our listener is. Otherwise the behavior of the super's onActionViewExpanded I was trying to change was still happening. The original answer is fine however, if you never wanted to change the super's behavior. I wanted to get rid of setQuery("") so it would remember the previous query when opened.

Comment: where we call MySearchView class? i have same problem